# Which component should control the loading state of a lower component?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, loading, state

Let's say I have these components:

```
Translator
  TranslationList
```

`Translator` determines translation context, has translate function.
`TranslationList` must show these "visual states": loading, result list, no results.

The `Translator` moves around the page (one instance): on focusing an input, it moves "below" it and gives a dropdown with suggestion.

So each time it moves, it has to:

- Show that it's loading translations
- Show translation list or no results message.

So my question is:

Which component should control the "loading" visual state?

If the `Translator` component controls it, it has to pass `loading=true translations=[]` as props to `Translation` list. Then later it has to rerender it again with new props `loading=false translations=[...]`. This seems a bit counter-intuitive, because `loading` feels like the state of the `TranslationList` component.

If we the `TranslationList` component has `loading` state, then it also has to have a way to `translate` things, meaning that I have to pass `translate` function as prop. I would then hold `translations` and `loading` as state. This all gets a bit messy, since it must now also receive string to translate, context.

I also don't want to have separate components for loading message, no results message. I'd rather keep these inside the `TranslationList`, because these 3 share that same wrapper `<div class="list-group"></div>`

Perhaps there should be one more Component in between these two components, responsible only for fetching translation data?

Answer (score 2):

**Translator component should control the loading state of a lower component list component**.  hold the loading and translating logic but with help by wrapping  it in a high order component where you should put most of the logic. link for HOC https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymJOm5jY1tQ.

```js
const translateSelected = wrappedComponent =>
  //return Translator component
  class extends React.Component {
  state = {translatedText: [], loading:true}
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("text to translate")
      .then(transText => this.setState({translatedText: transText, loading: false}))
  }
    render() {
    const {translatedText} = this.state
    return <WrappedComponent {..this.props} {...translatedText}
    }
  }

  const Translator_HOC = translateSelected(Translator);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a Higher Order Component to control the switching of the loading state and the `TranslationList`. That way you separate the loading display away from your TranslationList as being it's concern.  This also allows you to use the HOC in other areas.

The `Translator` can act as "container" component which does the data fetching/passing.

For example:

```
// The Loadable HOC
function Loadable(WrappedComponent) {
  return function LoadableComponent({ loaded, ...otherProps }) {
    return loaded 
      ? <WrappedComponent {...otherProps} />
      : <div>Loading...</div>
  }
}

// Translation list doesn't need to know about "loaded" prop
function TranslationList({ translations }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        translations.map((translation, index) =>
          <li key={index}>{translation}</li>                   
        )
      }
    </ul>
  )
}

// We create our new composed component here.
const LoadableTranslationList = Loadable(TranslationList)

class Translator extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loaded: false,
    translations: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Let's simulate a data fetch, typically you are going to access 
    // a prop like this.props.textToTranslate and then pass that to 
    // an API or redux action to fetch the respective translations.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true,
        translations: [ 'Bonjour', 'Goddag', 'Hola' ]
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() { 
    const { loaded, translations } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Translations for "{this.props.textToTranslate}"</h3>
        <LoadableTranslationList loaded={loaded} translations={translations}  />
      </div> 
    )  
  }  
}

ReactDOM.render(<Translate textToTranslate="Hello" />)
```

Running example here: http://www.webpackbin.com/NyQnWe54W